# Atualizar campo TIMESTAMP no On Update Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
Create Table tb_teste(
  cod_key integer not null,
  data_cad timestamp not null default now(),
  data_atualizacao timestamp not null default now(),
  primary key(cod_key)
)
```

No MySQL tenho a opção "...  ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Eu gostaria que o campo "data_atualizacao" tivesse a data e horas atualizados sempre que houver um update na tabela.

No Postgres tem essa opção ou preciso fazer Triggers/function?

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância mas `ON UPDATE` não se aplica a chaves estrangeiras? Não consegui encontrar tal opção no manual do SQL e também conferi no manual do PostgreSQL e não encontrei nada parecido.

Comment: Então o MySQL tem uma opção de criar a tabela com um ON UPDATE em campos timestamp... por default toda vez que a tabela sobre qualquer alteração ele faz o update com o valor data e hora atuais... é uma função muito interessante do MySQL, achei que tivesse algo assim no PostgreSQL, mas andei lendo o manual e também não achei não, só com triggers mesmo.

Comment: Interessante o manual do MySQL não mencionar tal opção ao explicar CREATE TABLE mas apenas ao explicar TIMESTAMP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035980/update-timestamp-when-row-is-updated-in-postgresql

Comment: Pois é... você declara assim: CAMPO_DATA TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
É muito prático